# Qtip chage onlick of element

Tags: qtip

I have a requirement to change the tooltip content on onclick event.

I am using tooltip 1.0.0 version

```
// will generate the html elements for tooltip with expand text
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('.tooltip[tooltip]').each(function()
{

  $(this).qtip({

    content: $(this).attr('tooltip'),

    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: 'mouseout',
    style: {
        name: "dark",
        width: { max: 550, min: 100 },
        border: {
            width: 1,
            radius: 3
         }
    }

  });
});
});

function toggle(aRow) {                
   // logic to toggle the expand and collapse

   // Here when content toggled I need to change tooltip content as well.. Can you help me on doing this?
}       

<table>
    <tr onlick="toggle(this);" class="tooltip" tooltip="Expand"> Apple .... </tr> //onclick will expand the value
</table>
```

On mouseclick event content of tr tag will get changed and we need to change tooltip accordingly. Please help me with this.

Comment: Probably something like `$(aRow).('option', 'content.text', 'new content here')` - according to the new and old [API](http://qtip2.com/api)

Comment: Below is js method. It did not work. Your help is appreciated.
 
 function toggle(aRow) {                 
  if(aRow.innerHTML=="Apple ...") {
   aRow.innerHTML=="Apple6 is from Apple Inc";
   aRow.qtip('option', 'content.text', 'Collapse')
  }
  else {
   aRow.innerHTML=="Apple ..."
   aRow.qtip.('option', 'content.text', 'Expand')
  }
 }

Comment: Got this error:   Uncaught TypeError: aRow.qtip is not a function

Comment: I tried $(aRow).qtip.('option', 'content.text', 'Expand');

Comment: Typo in your code: `onlick` → `onclick`